# UI Testing swipe-to-delete table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to build a UI test in a basic shopping list app that makes sure swiping to delete a table view cell does in fact delete the cell from the table view.

I am running the test code below, but when it comes time to swipe the table view cell left (to display the delete button), it doesn't swipe.  It appears that it may be tapping it, but it doesn't swipe. Because of this, the test fails when trying to tap the Delete button because "No matches found for button."

How does one test swipe to delete in a table view?

```
    func testDeletingCell() {
       let app = XCUIApplication()
       app.navigationBars["ShoppingList.ShoppingListView"].buttons["Add"].tap()

       let element = app.otherElements.containing(.navigationBar, identifier:"ShoppingList.AddShoppingListItemView").children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element
       let textField = element.children(matching: .textField).element(boundBy: 0)
       textField.tap()
       textField.typeText("abc")

       let textField2 = element.children(matching: .textField).element(boundBy: 1)
       textField2.tap()
       textField2.typeText("123")
       app.navigationBars["ShoppingList.AddShoppingListItemView"].buttons["Save"].tap()

       let tablesQuery = app.tables
       tablesQuery.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 0).staticTexts["123"].swipeLeft()
       tablesQuery.buttons["Delete"].tap()

       XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.count == 0)
   }
```

Comment: Is the 123 element being found correctly? And if you watch the simulator, is it actually being swiped?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this new `Swift 3` syntax instead:

```
let tablesQuery = app.tables.cells
tablesQuery.element(boundBy: 0).swipeLeft()
tablesQuery.element(boundBy: 0).buttons["Delete"].tap()
```

Comment: This was the answer.  Thanks, Rashwan.

Comment: @Josh, np glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode 12.4** | **Swift 5**

Delete all cells inside a UITableView in XCTestCase:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()

//Ensure your UIViewController loaded with data
sleep(5)

let tablesQuery = app.tables["<YourTableViewIdentifier>"].cells         
for i in 0..<tablesQuery.allElementsBoundByAccessibilityElement.count{
    tablesQuery.element(boundBy: 0).swipeLeft()
    //Sometimes the swipeLeft() itself is enough to delete the cell,
    //but if it is not use what @Rashwan L suggests
    //tablesQuery.element(boundBy: 0).buttons["Delete"].tap()
}         
XCTAssertEqual(tablesQuery.allElementsBoundByAccessibilityElement.count, 0)
```

The reason I don't swipe left and then tap delete is because swipeLeft() was already enough to deleted my cell from the UITableView.

If you want to swipe left on a cell and ensure it won't be deleted use:

```
swipeLeft(velocity: .slow)
```

This velocity is a XCUIGestureVelocity and you can set it to .fast, .slow, or its .default.

Comment: Hey Sebastian, while writing my tests, I came across your solution as mine was failing badly: 
 while !cells.isEmpty {
            cells[0].swipeLeft()
            cells[0].buttons["Delete"].tap()
        }
Failed to get matching snapshot: No matches found for Descendants matching type Table from input {(
    Application, pid: 1233
)}

Do you happen to know why is that?